# Retrieving an updated "checked" field of a checkbox in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following checkbox code:

```
<input checked="checked" id="check" name="check" type="checkbox" value="active">
```

It's set to `checked` by default, and doesn't change whether the user unchecks it or not in the UI.  How can I find out whether the user actually unchecked the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```
alert(check.checked)
```

Checkbox input elements have a `checked` property, even if you can't see it, as long as the click event gets to them, the value will toggle.

That's how you can check, now if you want to react to that:

```
check.onchange = function() {
    if (!check.checked) {
         // he unchecked the box! oh my
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the input element's `checked` property changes when I check and uncheck the box (when retrieved by JS).  However, when I attempt to send this data to my Rails controller, it sends whatever the original value was.

Comment: And I imagine you get the value on the spot right? Maybe the bug is around that part of the code D:

Comment: My browser was using a cached version of my js file.  Clearing the cache fixed the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener("change", function() {
  var checkbox_value = document.querySelector('#check:checked').value;

  alert(checkbox_value);
});
```